# What is the difference between X_test, X_train, y_test, y_train in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, supervised-learning

I'm learning sklearn and I didn't understand very good the difference and why use 4 outputs with the function `train_test_split()`.

In the Documentation, I found some examples but it wasn't sufficient to end my doubts.

Does the code use the `X_train` to predict the `X_test` or use the `X_train` to predict the `y_test`?

What is the difference between train and test? Do I use train to predict the test or something similar?

I'm very confused about it. I will let below the example provided in the Documentation.

```
>>> import numpy as np  
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
>>> X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)  
>>> X
array([[0, 1], 
       [2, 3],  
       [4, 5],  
       [6, 7],  
       [8, 9]])  
>>> list(y)  
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(  
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)  
...  
>>> X_train  
array([[4, 5], 
       [0, 1],  
       [6, 7]])  
>>> y_train  
[2, 0, 3]  
>>> X_test  
array([[2, 3], 
       [8, 9]])  
>>> y_test  
[1, 4]  
>>> train_test_split(y, shuffle=False)  
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Difference between train and test is something you should learn in a basic machine learning course or a book, its a concept you must learn before using any ML library

Comment: I've edited, because (uppercase) X_train is a 2-D matrix, whereas (lowercase) y_train is 1-D array

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Below is a dummy `pandas.DataFrame` for example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report

df = pd.DataFrame({'X1':[100,120,140,200,230,400,500,540,600,625],
                       'X2':[14,15,22,24,23,31,33,35,40,40],
                       'Y':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
```

Here we have 3 columns, `X1,X2,Y`
suppose `X1 & X2` are your independent variables and `'Y'` column is your dependent variable.

```
X = df[['X1','X2']]
y = df['Y']
```

With `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` you are creating 4 portions of data which will be used for fitting & predicting values.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4,random_state=42) 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

Now

**1). X_train** - This includes your all independent variables,these will be used to train the model, also as we have specified the `test_size = 0.4`, this means `60%` of observations from your complete data will be used to train/fit the model and rest `40%` will be used to test the model.

**2). X_test** - This is remaining `40%` portion of the independent variables from the data which will not be used in the training phase and will be used to make predictions to test the accuracy of the model.

**3). y_train** - This is your dependent variable which needs to be predicted by this model, this includes category labels against your independent variables, we need to specify our dependent variable while training/fitting the model.

**4). y_test** - This data has category labels for your test data, these labels will be used to test the accuracy between actual and predicted categories.

Now you can fit a model on this data, let's fit `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train) #This is where the training is taking place
y_pred_logreg = logreg.predict(X_test) #Making predictions to test the model on test data
print('Logistic Regression Train accuracy %s' % logreg.score(X_train, y_train)) #Train accuracy
#Logistic Regression Train accuracy 0.8333333333333334
print('Logistic Regression Test accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred_logreg, y_test)) #Test accuracy
#Logistic Regression Test accuracy 0.5
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_logreg)) #Confusion matrix
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_logreg)) #Classification Report
```

You can read more about metrics [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics)

Read more about data split [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 13):

Let's say we have this data

```
Age    Sex       Disease
----  ------ |  ---------
  
  X_train    |   y_train   )
                           )
 5       F   |  A Disease  )
 15      M   |  B Disease  ) 
 23      M   |  B Disease  ) training
 39      M   |  B Disease  ) data
 61      F   |  C Disease  )
 55      M   |  F Disease  )
 76      F   |  D Disease  )
 88      F   |  G Disease  )
-------------|------------
   
  X_test     |    y_test

 63      M   |  C Disease  )
 46      F   |  C Disease  ) test
 28      M   |  B Disease  ) data
 33      F   |  B Disease  )
```

`X_train` contains the values of the features (age and sex => training data)

`y_train` contains the target output corresponding to `X_train` values (disease => training data) (what values we should find after training process)

There are also values generated after training process (predictions) which should be very close or the same with  `y_train` values if the model is a successful one.

`X_test` contains the values of the features to be tested after training (age and sex => test data)

`y_test` contains the target output (disease => test data) corresponding to `X_test` (age and sex => training data) and will be compared to prediction value with given `X_test` values of the model after training in order to determine how successful the model is.

Comment: Your graphicall approach helps. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 4):

You're supposed to train your classifier / regressor using your training set, and test / evaluate it using your testing set.

Your classifier / regressor uses `x_train` to predict `y_pred` and uses the difference between `y_pred` and `y_train` (through a loss function) to learn. Then you evaluate it by computing the loss between the predictions of `x_test` (that could also be named `y_pred`), and `y_test`.

Comment: I've edited, because (uppercase) X_train is a 2-D matrix, whereas (lowercase) y_train is 1-D array

Answer (score 1):

Consider X as 1000 data points and Y as integer class label   (to which class each data point belongs)

Eg:
X = [1.24 2.36 3.24 ... (1000 terms)
Y = [1,0,0,1.....(1000 terms)]

We are splitting in 600:400 ratio

X_train => will have 600 data points
X_test => will have class labels corresponding to 400 data points

Y_train => will have 600 data points
Y_test => will have class labels corresponding to 400 data points

Comment: should it not be with X_train and Y_train both have 600 while X_test and Y_test both have 400?