# Python xgb: ValueError: "feature_names mismatch"

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm trying to learn the basics of XGBoost and devises a script that splits some data I found on Kaggle about Corona virus outbreaks in China. The code and model work, but some some reason when I use the model to make a new prediction I get a "ValueError: feature_names mismatch." The new test data has a 2-d array with 2 values, just like the test data, but I still get a value error.

```
train = df[['RegionCode','ProvinceCode']].astype(int)
test = df['infected'].astype(int)

X_test, X_train, y_test, y_train = train_test_split(train, test, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
test = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)

param = {
'max_depth':4,
'eta':0.3,
'num_class': 2}
epochs = 10

model = xgb.train(param, train, epochs)
```

All the code above works, but the terst below gives me the error:

```
testArray=np.array([[13, 67]])

test_individual = xgb.DMatrix(testArray)

print(model.predict(test_individual))
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are not splitting the data properly, please go through my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636444/what-is-the-difference-between-x-test-x-train-y-test-y-train-in-sklearn/60637924?noredirect=1#comment107322867_60637924) on another post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing out on the basics of using the train_test_split function of sklearn.

```
X_test, X_train, y_test, y_train = train_test_split(train, test, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

The line above expects the **train** to have all the features to be used for training, while the **test** expects the target feature.

Try fixing that first.

Comment: But isn't that what I'm doing? I have train = df[['RegionCode','ProvinceCode']].astype(int)
and test = df['infected'].astype(int). train is my features and test is target.

Comment: Oh! I just had a look again. You need to provide the column names in the testArray that you are taking. That would solve it.

Comment: Thank you! I don't quite understand what you mean by providing the column name? I specify int for the new X value, so where would I input the column names? Can you provide a sample of what you mean? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Create a dataframe with one row [13, 67] and the same column names as provided in the train i.e. ['RegionCode','ProvinceCode'] , then try using the predict function. Hope that works